# Is it possible to have stylus compile automatically via res.render or app.render (not a route)?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, stylus

Much like the way `stylus` middleware automatically compiles needed css for a template (jade in my case) when a route is triggered, is there a way to do it automatically outside of the route -> middleware flow?

I have a build system where I render some html files via `app.render` and then save them to the filesystem (many people do similar for email templates). I want to make sure that when I `app.render("foo.jade", func...`, that any of the .css files needed by `foo.jade` are automatically compiled from their `styl` counterparts. This happens perfectly and automatically if I have a route that renders `foo.jade`, but in this case, there are no routes. I understand that I can use `stylus'` api and call `stylus.render`, but that would mean I'd have to specify and render every one of the `styl/css` files needed by my template "by hand."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make sure that when I app.render("foo.jade", func..., that any of the .css files needed by foo.jade are automatically compiled from their styl counterparts

If you want to do that ahead of time, as in when `foo.jade` is rendered as opposed to when `GET /foo.css` is requested, no there's almost certainly nothing that is going to parse you HTML on the way out to the filesystem and dynamically render all referenced CSS. At least not exactly to your specifications. However, there do exist [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code) to read an HTML file  and inline it's referenced CSS, so you may be able to run your HTML through those.

You may want to look at [juice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice) but since it's geared toward email and inlines CSS into the HTML itself, it may not do what you want (which is probably generating .css files next to the HTML).

My suggestion is parse the HTML for linked CSS URLs yourself and render the corresponding stylus to disk appropriately. Use consistent patterns and you should be able to handle all your templates with one or just a few functions.

However, if you want to render stylus to CSS on the fly when a `GET /foo.css` request comes in, sure there are existing middlewares to do that or you could role your own. And no, you wouldn't need a route for every CSS path, just some URL patterns/params and good old programming.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer, mine is not emails. I was just saying I'm using app.render the way "some" people do emails. Probably shouldn't have mentioned email. And what I want to do is exactly as you said, "ahead of time, as in when `foo.jade` is rendered"

Comment: I ended up using `stylus`' built-in [.render](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html) function and just iterating through my directory of `.styl` files and writing them to my `public/css` folder on server start. Thanks for confirming.